# In contemporary mathematics, is there a research field that deals with (i.e. based on) General Topology (i.e. point-set topology)?

Tags: gn.general-topology

In contemporary mathematics, is there a research field  that deals with (i.e. based on) General Topology (i.e. point-set topology)?

If there is, I would be thankful to get links to papers that could lead me to this subject.

Also, if this is not the right place for a question like that, I would be grateful for a guidance to a more suitable cite

- edit: I don't refer to Algebraic or Geometric-group topology. But topics closer to the more abstract-set-theory characteristics of Topology

Thanks

Comment: Isn't "general topology" a research field in contemporary mathematics?

Comment: The MO member @Taras Banakh ist very active in this field.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/archive/math has the category of general topology (.GN) for "continuum theory, point-set topology, spaces with algebraic structure, foundations, dimension theory, local and global properties", which is distinct from both algebraic topology (.AT) and geometric topology (.GT)

Comment: A useful overview of contemporary research in general topology is [**Encyclopedia of General Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0444503552) edited by Hart/Nagata/Vaughan.

Comment: The MSC subject number for general topology is 54. This is clearly a current research subject since Mathscinet lists 849 publications in 2020 for this subject, and 732 for 2021.